# Ajax script does not update DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a little Ajax script that executes a POST and returns the result on screen.
I debugged the script and I can see that the POST is successful, however I cannot get the result displayed on screen. It looks like I need an extra refresh or something. Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks in advance
Regards

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#vehicleMessages").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxPost();

    });

});

function ajaxPost() {

    var form = $("#vehicleMessages");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: form.attr("action") + "?tripId=" + $("#tripId").val() + "&partitionKey=" + $("#partitionKey").val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.status == "Done") {
                $("#postResult").html("Result: " + result.data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Doest this `result.status == "Done"` evaluate to true?

Comment: Your contentType is not json.  It is a query string.  Take off that argument.  Unless it should be json in which case you are passing the data incorrectly.

Comment: removing the result.stats == "Done" did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to be sure that the `result.status` is "Done".
2. You have to be sure that the `result.data` is text or HTML-text

I suggest you to try this:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json",
     url: form.attr("action") + "?tripId=" + $("#tripId").val() + "&partitionKey=" + $("#partitionKey").val(),
     dataType: 'json'
 }).then(function (result) {
     if (result.status == "Done") {
         $("#postResult").html("Result: " + result.data);
     }
 });
```